# cannot import name 'Stocker'

Tags: python

cannot import name 'Stocker' from 'stocker' (C:\Users\Colter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\stocker_*init*_.py)

I'm getting this error with my stocker import, anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

This is the program:

```
import tensorflow
from stocker import Stocker

amazon = Stocker('AMZN')
```

I'm using python 3.8 in Visual Studio if that helps.
pip install confirms the "Requirement already satisfied" for stocker.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned the error, but didn't actually post it.

I'm assuming [this](https://pypi.org/project/stocker/) is the package you are referring to. Their readme doesn't really say much about how it is supposed to be used (only has one example). But looking at the source code, it doesn't seem like `Stocker` is one of the objects in that package.

They do have in their repo a [tutorial](https://github.com/jcamiloangarita/stocker/blob/master/tutorial/Stocker%20-%20Analysis.ipynb) that you can check out to see some other examples (though I didn't find them very useful either, but stocks is not my field of expertise at all).

It should be something like:

```
from stocker.predict import tomorrow # this one predicts the value of the stock tomorrow
from stocker import get_data # this one has lots of methods to get info from the stock

stock = "AMZN"

# predict the value:
print(tomorrow(stock))

# examples of methods in get_data
# Company name
print(get_data.company_name(stock))
# finding interest for 'stock' during 'timeframe'
print(get_data.get_interest(stock, timeframe)
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I was able to figure out how to scrape the data I needed and still use stocker. However, I think 'stocker' and 'Stocker' are two separate packages. The Stocker package gets placed into the stocker directory. On the Stocker github he mentions how you should open a document in Jupiter Notebook from the stocker directory. My stocker directory is in a hidden appdata folder, currently making the folder unhidden to try using Stocker.

Comment: Oh.. I see. I just found [this other package](https://github.com/WillKoehrsen/Data-Analysis/tree/master/stocker) that seems to be the one you're using. My bad.

It is odd that you would have to run your Jupyter notebook in the same directory. Perhaps what's missing is for the package path to be added to your $PATH so you can access it from any directory

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have installed a different package with the same name. If you used pip to install it, you have most likely installed [this Stocker](https://pypi.org/project/stocker/) package, while you intended to install [this Stocker](https://github.com/bobbruno/stocker) package.

Here is the documentation for the intended Stocker: https://github.com/bobbruno/stocker/blob/master/readme.md